# Convert react dispatch arrow function to tyescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

In my ES6 javascript react/redux code I have something like:

```
export const myFunction = params => dispatch => {
   ...code
   dispatch(...)
}
```

How I can convert this to typescript? And not using Redux but React [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

My failed attempt was:

```
export const myFunction = (payload: any): void => dispatch:any => {
  ...code
  dispatch(...)
}
```

got the errors:

- Parameter 'dispatch' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)
- List item Type '(dispatch: any) => void' is not assignable to type 'void'.ts(2322)

Comment: The return type of `myFunction` is another function, but you’ve declared its return type as `void`. That’s what the second error means.

Comment: `export const myFunction = (payload: any) => (dispatch: (action: any) => void, getState: () => GlobalState) => {` Where `GlobalState` would be whatever your total state type definition is (the combination of your reducers)

Comment: All ES6 functions are valid TypeScript, there really is no point in converting to TypeScript if you are just adding type any as that doesn't add any value. The value of TypeScript is the types and any defeats that purpose.

Comment: the any is just an example, I don't know which type to use. that's why any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you trying to achieve is works in Redux and facilitated bu [Redux-thunk middleware](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk). Middlewares are not present in `useReducer` hook. So out of the box this is not possible.

But you can write your own middleware like this

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface FuncState {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: string;
}

interface FunctAction1 {
    type: 'SET_PROP1';  // Action type property has type of 'SET_PROP1'. This is not string, it is type 'SET_PROP1'. The only value type may have is 'SET_PROP1'.
    prop1: string;
}

interface FunctAction2 {
    type: 'SET_PROP2';
    prop2: string;
}

// Here we create union of actions to properly type Reducer
type KnownActions = FunctAction1 | FunctAction2;

const FuncInitState: FuncState = {
    prop1: '',
    prop2: ''
}

function isFunction(f: any): f is Function {
    return typeof f === "function";
}

function useThunkReducer<S, A>(reducer: React.Reducer<S, A>, initialState: React.ReducerState<React.Reducer<S, A>>):
[S, (action: A | ((dispatch: React.Dispatch<A>, state: S) => void)) => void] 
{

    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);

    // Essentially this is middleware
    const thunkDispatch = (action: A
        | ((dispatch: React.Dispatch<A>, state: S) => void)): void => {
        if (isFunction(action)) { // This is type guard
            return action(dispatch, state);
        }

        return dispatch(action);
    };

    return [state, thunkDispatch];
}

const FuncReducer: React.Reducer<FuncState, KnownActions> = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_PROP1':  
            // action will have type of FunctAction1 as action.type has value 'SET_PROP1'
            return { ...state, prop1: action.prop1 }
        case 'SET_PROP2':
            return { ...state, prop2: action.prop2 }
        default:
            throw new Error('FuncReducer do not have default');
    }
}

const myClickAction = (prop1: string) => (dispatch: React.Dispatch<KnownActions>) => {
    console.log(prop1);
    dispatch({ type: 'SET_PROP1', prop1: "some value" });
}

const FuncCmp: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useThunkReducer(FuncReducer, FuncInitState);
    return <div>
        FuncCmp
        <button onClick={(e) => dispatch(myClickAction("some value"))}>Set prop1</button>
        <button onClick={(e) => dispatch({ type: 'SET_PROP2', prop2: "another value" })}>Set prop2</button>
        <div>Prop1: {state.prop1}</div>
        <div>Prop2: {state.prop2}</div>
        </div>;
}
```

I've added comments to code for clarity.

And working sample is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/so56893971-nlyxh)

Comment: what I wanna do is: 
`onClick={ (e) => dispatch(myClickAtion())`
where

`myClickAction() => {
 ...some code
  dispatch({ type: 'SET_PROP1', prop1: "some value" })
}`

Comment: I've updated the answer to showcase how it is possible.